# How to sum the bottom value of a column that changes size?

Tags: excel

So I'm tracking some investments in excel and the columns of interest are the total value of investments, the value for each investment, date. I have a formula for the net total to the side and I'm using this to manually type the net total into the column. I'm also using this data to create graphs of value vs date.

How can I change this formula so it will always just add up the final values for the total of each investments? I dont want to have to manually fudge the formula everytime I update the tables.

I want to do this because the table is a bit busy due to the data needed for the graphs, it'd be nice just to have the net total by the side and highlighted.

```
net total   date          1      2      3

  111      13/01/18      100     10     1        Net total: `Sum(c2, d2, e2)`
  121      14/01/18      100     20     1
```

So I want the net total to just sum the bottom values for columns titled 1, 2, 3. I want it to be dynamic so i can then just type in the net total into the correct column and i can update all the graphs. But also want the net total to be on the side for easy viewing too instead of it getting lost in the raw data

Comment: can you show how your data is laid out and give some example data with expected outcome? It also helps to post your efforts and describe the problems you are having.

Comment: re: *'How can I change this formula...'* **what** formula?

Comment: Sorry I've updated it now, the formula for net total

Answer (score 0):

there is a trick using "lookup()":

search(999999;A:A) returns value equals to 999999 or last value if 999999 is greater than every values. So your formula will be:

Net total:  "**lookup(999999999;C:C)+lookup(999999999;D:D)+lookup(999999999;E:E)**"

(assuming none of the values is greatrer than 999999999)

Answer (score 0):

Will the final value from each column always be the same row? If so then this formula will sum the last row in columns B, C and D by finding the last number in column B

`=SUM(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(99^99,B:B),0))`

Comment: No, the final value will move down the spreadsheet as there are more rows inserted as it gets updated. I think I'm just going to do a workaround where I can make a formula which will tell me the highest row number  then using this to look up the must up-to-date row. I'm not sure if that makes sense so I'll post the code once I've worked it out and put it in

Comment: I know the row changes but what I meant was will the bottom row for column B be the same as the bottom row for column C and D? If so you can use the formula I suggested above

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you mean. Yes they're all level. I ended up using `=LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B<>""),ROW(B:B))` to get like an index (then hid the cell) and then used `=(INDEX(B:B,MAX(P:P))) + (INDEX(H:H,MAX(P:P))) + (INDEX(K:K,MAX(P:P)))` to get the net sum

Comment: Perhaps you could use this formula for net sum in one go: `=LOOKUP(99^99,B:B,B:B+H:H+K:K)`